# How does sampling work when updating statistics?

Tags: sql-server, statistics

I have several massive tables. I'd like to ensure their statistics are up to date via a weekly maintenance plan.

However, doing so is taking too much time.

If I specify

```
WITH SAMPLE 50 PERCENT
```

does SQL Server then sample:

1. the first 50% of pages
2. every other page
3. or some other strategy?

[BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) is not clear on this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For `WITH SAMPLE 50 PERCENT` it works as though for each data page in the table SQL Server flips a coin. If it lands heads then it reads all the rows on the page. If it lands tails then it reads none.

Tracing the `UPDATE STATISTICS T WITH SAMPLE 50 PERCENT` call in Profiler shows the following query is emitted

```
SELECT StatMan([SC0], [SB0000])
FROM   (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [SC0],
                               step_direction([SC0]) OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS [SB0000]
        FROM   (SELECT [C] AS [SC0]
                FROM   [dbo].[T] TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (5.000000e+001 PERCENT) 
                WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL_HELPER
        ORDER  BY [SC0],
                  [SB0000]) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

With Plan

[image]

`TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (5.000000e+001 PERCENT)` is responsible for the sampling and [is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189108(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM` returns an approximate percentage of rows and
> generates a random value for each physical 8-KB page in the table.
> Based on the random value for a page and the percentage specified in
> the query, a page is either included in the sample or excluded. Each
> page that is included returns all rows in the sample result set.

The documentation  also states

> Although the plan shows a table scan is performed, only those pages
> that are included in the result set are actually required to be read
> from the data file.

The `STATMAN` call is to an internal aggregate function [briefly described here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/statistics-damned-lies-and-statistics-what-is-statman/)